# Persistent application for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, background-process

I am trying to develop an application that needs to be running persistently in iOS in background mode and never gets closed even when you don't have internet access(3g or WiFi). I wonder if its possible to have it running at all times except when you choose to close it manually.

Comment: I've removed your opening paragraph as it was the only thing that was popping up in the question preview on the front page - the actual question was not visible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simple anser: NO.

You can get an app to run in the background if it is playing audio, is a VOIP client or need to track the location.

But there is no way to make it persistent, the user can always kill the app.
And if needed to system could kill the app if to much memory is used.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
The application will be always running in the background to track the location.
Of course there is no problem if the user kills it. What concerns me then is if there is any way to keep the application running even when the system needs the memory to run another application.

Comment: Just make sure that when your get backgrounded you clean up a much memory as you can. Also when your app does receive a memory warning clean up any unneeded retained data and you should be fine.

Comment: This might be a very basic question but, you mean that the program internally receives memory warnings and you can code to clean up the unneeded data or used memory when that happens?
The cleaning of unneeded data would be only for my application or would also include the whole system unneeded data?

Answer (score 0):

it depends on what you mean, do you mean it keeps running even though the autolock tries to lock the iPhone after e.g. 2 minutes? Because then the answer is yes, use the idleTimerDisabled property of the [UIApplication sharedApplication]. You can disable the autolock here so your app keeps showing and the iPhone doesn't lock automatically.

Comment: The application is intended to work in the background. There is no interface apart from the settings.
Even when the phone is locked I would like it to keep running unless the user decides to kill it manually.

Comment: Ah but you have to have an interface! At least to get it approved by Apple. Anyway, if you simply use the location of the user you can keep it running in the background :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll try with the location tracking always enabled.